# casperjs response headers content-length 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, phantomjs, casperjs

Using Casperjs i am downloading some apk from remote server but getting an empty apk (0 bytes).

```
try {
        this.echo("Attempting to download file ");
        var fs = require('fs');
        var appUrl = 'http://website.com/download/someapp.apk';
        casper.download(appUrl, fs.workingDirectory+'/'+'newApk.apk');
    } catch (e) {
        this.echo(e);
    }
```

And I am getting this in response Headers.

```
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Mon, 15 May 2017 06:49:10 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
Location:http://website.com/download/someapp.apk
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-
revalidate, proxy-revalidate, no-transform
Pragma: no-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is correct and your code valid, it should work. To help you, here is a minimal working example script that downloads an image in the current directory:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://duckduckgo.com', function() {
  var url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/assets/logo_homepage.normal.v107.svg';
  this.download(url, 'duckduckgo-logo.svg');
});

casper.run(function() {
  this.echo('Done.').exit();
});
```

If it still does not work, it may be an issue with *security*. In this case, try to run your script with `casperjs --web-security=no download.js` or configure your Casper instance like so:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  pageSettings: {
    webSecurityEnabled: false
  }
});
```

**OR**

```
casper.page.settings.webSecurityEnabled = false;
```